# Laravel is echoing the number of the array instead of the value

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how to explain it but laravel won't let me print the value, but instead just echo's the key?

This is my code, I've tried everything I could, I don't know what's wrong..

```
 <span>{!! $subject[$i] !!}</span>
```

It is in a for loop that works on other variables so that's not the problem, this is my controller function

```
  public function assignments()
    {
        $title = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_title');
        $context = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_context');
        $subject = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_subject');
        $day = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_due_day');
        $colour = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_colour');
        $id = DB::table('assignments')->where('assignments_completed', '0')->lists('assignments_id');
        $subjectName = DB::table('class')->where('class_active', '1')->lists('className');

        return View::make('pages.assignments', array(
            'id' => $id,
            'title' => $title,
            'context' => $context,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'day' => $day,
            'colour' => $colour,
            'pageTitle' => 'Assignments',
            'sub' => $subjectName
        ));
    }
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: so you saying it's working with all other variables, like title?

Comment: Yes it is, and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, all I had to do was create another array from the class table

```
  $subjectName = DB::table('class')->where('class_active', '1')->lists('className');
```

and use the numbers my scripts was echoing as the key for the new `$subjectName` array.

So instead I was echoing out `{!! $sub[$subject[$i]] !!}`

I'm sure there's an easier way but I'm satisfied with a working model.